# Please suggest compatible AES encryption and decryption between flutter and ruby based backend

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, flutter, encryption

Currently certain sensitive data parameters like User ID & password are transmitted in plain-text in my app. I am looking for a solution for encryption based data transmission (AES) between my app and backend. My backend is based on Ruby on Rails(ROR). I've tried searching on how to achieve the same between flutter and ROR based backend, but didn't find any resources.Please help with any available solution or provide links to achieve the same

Our testing team did packet capture using Burpsuite app and in that they found credentials like id and password as a plain text. How to encrypt that?

Comment: You can use bouncy castle android implementation for all your encryption / decryption related work on Android

Comment: How to achieve this in flutter?

Comment: Use HTTPS or TLS (including Websockets `wss`) unless you're specifically talking about encryption at rest.

Comment: @Pacific you can check the Pointy Castle implementation for flutter https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to encrypt data going to your server yourself.  Use HTTPS.  The S means it uses the SSL encryption protocol.  Any data sent over HTTPS is already encrypted.  Encrypting it again won't help, and depending on the method can actually make it less secure.  And I promise the built in peer reviewed library is going to be far more secure than anything you roll on your own.

If you're not using HTTPS-  start.  There's a reason why its become the default, many browsers won't even visit non HTTPS sites by default.  Android won't send plain HTTP data by default either.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But our testing team did packet capture using BurpSuite and in that id password was visible as plain text. So how to solve that?

Comment: And our API's are also https based

Comment: Apparently not if you can pull plaintext from the wire. That is *impossible* with HTTPS. It's good you're looking for this, but it's also bad that you were able to find it so easily.

Comment: @Pacific You cannot capture https traffic on the wire.  Either you're NOT using HTTPS, they're not capturing it on the wire (they're doing something like capturing it at the library level), or they just broke the security of every server in the world including every bank in the world.  Or they're just making shit up.  Maybe you're doing something like HTTP for analytics.  But HTTPS coming onto the wire is encrypted and you can't break it unless you've pulled off a successful man in the middle attack

Comment: Yes, they are doing MITM attack. How do I safeguard my app from it or any other similar type of attack?

Comment: Depends on how they're doing it.  If they're using your cert's private key there's no preventing that, but you should be keeping that on lockdown as an organization.  If anyone gets that you're screwed.  If they're doing it without your cert you'd need to know a lot more details.  But then we're getting WAY beyond the scope of a SO question, you're basically looking to become a security expert.  But given that every bank in the world with online banking just relies on HTTPS, I don't think you need to worry about additional encryption (and it may not make things better anyway).